# java images not showing up

Tags: java, image, loops, for-loop, copy

I am writing a program where I take separate images and copy them  as one whole picture in one template. But I cant figure out how to copy the separate images so they are not on top of each other. I noticed the first and second images are copied and placed next to each other to form the image, but then after that the three other images just pile on top of the second image. I cant figure out 
how to separate them to complete the image. If someone could tell me how to fix this problem that would be great.
Thanks

My code:

```
import java.awt.*;
class PanoramaTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Picture sourcePicture = new Picture("Mars1.jpg");
        Picture sourcePicture2 = new Picture("Mars2.jpg");
        Picture sourcePicture3 = new Picture("Mars3.jpg");
        Picture sourcePicture4 = new Picture("Mars4.jpg");
        Picture sourcePicture5 = new Picture("Mars5.jpg");
        Picture targetPicture1 = new Picture(1150,400);

        Pixel sourcePixel, targetPixel = null;
        Color sourceColor, targetColor = null;

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x,y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture2.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture2.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture2.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture.getWidth(), y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture3.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture3.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture3.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture2.getWidth(), y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture4.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture4.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture4.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture3.getWidth(), y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < sourcePicture5.getHeight(); y++)
        {
        for(int x = 0; x < sourcePicture5.getWidth(); x++)
            {
                sourcePixel = sourcePicture5.getPixel(x,y);
                sourceColor = sourcePixel.getColor();
                targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture4.getWidth(), y);
                targetPixel.setColor(sourceColor);
            }
        }

        targetPicture1.show();
        targetPicture1.write("FinalPanorama.jpg");
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here, from a quick review of the code, is that likely all of your source pictures are *about* the same size if not exactly.

So, when you draw the first picture, you draw it using the left side as an offset, because you don't "add" anything to the location:

```
targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x,y);
```

The second picture you "add" the width of a picture to the x position like this:

```
targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture.getWidth(), y);
```

For the third, you try to do the same thing, but you only use the width of the second picture:

```
targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture2.getWidth(), y);
```

If we assume that sourcePicture2 is approximately the same width as sourcePicture then we are drawing the third picture over the second instead of drawing it offset by both the width of sourcePicture2 + sourcePicture

e.g.:

```
targetPixel = targetPicture1.getPixel(x + sourcePicture.getWidth() + sourcePicture2.getWidth(), y);
```

This way, it pushes the third picture so that it is offset by the width of both of the pictures drawn before.